# NiFi using memory more than allocated

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, apache-nifi, ambari

We have done the NiFi upgradation from `1.18.0` to `1.19.1` and we also upgrade the java version from 8 to 11 and after upgradation we observe nifi using more memory than allocated and caching build in the nifi. we allocate memory to nifi as **java.arg.2=-Xms1g and java.arg.3=-Xmx50g**. we are using `RAM-64 GB` and `Core-8` and the solid-state high-speed hard disk is `2T`. OS is `CentOS7.9`, ARM64 hardware architecture. we uncomment the Garbage collector from bootstarp.conf but this is not useful for us. we keep the databasr repository, content repository, provenance repository, and flowfile repository in different disks.

we uncomment the Garbage collector from bootstarp.conf but this is not useful for us.

I need a help to resolve the issue

**nifi-app.log for reference**

```
id=1682607799237-15502, container=contS1R1, section=142], offset=605303, length=7664],offset=0,name=47ffd206-8189-4fbb-9d19-2b82113da956,size=7664], StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=a06c6ecd-167f-41d6-9ec5-1bcadc37fcf6,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1682607797216-15364, container=contS1R1, section=4], offset=874085, length=11888],offset=0,name=675ad88e-c9e1-4b2f-85a0-c2b842e6c35b,size=11888], StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=6b21da95-95d9-46f5-8510-4710ef197819,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1682607797216-15364, container=contS1R1, section=4], offset=864517, length=9568],offset=0,name=3b608669-9dee-4286-8865-695ca9f60105,size=9568], StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=dadb08dd-ee7d-4c70-ade8-14e6b42f89e5,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1682607799314-15505, container=contS1R2, section=145], offset=0, length=12576],offset=0,name=52a965fe-4d18-499f-9f88-3ab1c84f836d,size=12576]] (40.72 KB) from Peer[url=nifi://212.76.88.137:8445] in 2625 milliseconds at a rate of 15.51 KB/sec
2023-04-27 15:03:22,539 INFO [FileSystemRepository Workers Thread-2] o.a.n.c.repository.FileSystemRepository Successfully archived 23 Resource Claims for Container contS1R2 in 2 millis
2023-04-27 15:03:22,663 INFO [FileSystemRepository Workers Thread-2] o.a.n.c.repository.FileSystemRepository Successfully archived 38 Resource Claims for Container contS1R1 in 124 millis
2023-04-27 15:03:22,740 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3586] o.a.n.c.r.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Successfully swapped out 10000 FlowFiles from FlowFileQueue[id=ad7834f7-38a1-16f4-4961-0e68a6faca29] to Swap File /data1/flowfile_repository/swap/1682607800425-ad7834f7-38a1-16f4-4961-0e68a6faca29-2ca046bb-321a-43f0-8ffc-12f6eebb77e3.swap
2023-04-27 15:03:22,788 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-2522] o.a.n.r.p.s.SocketFlowFileServerProtocol SocketFlowFileServerProtocol[CommsID=ce5942ca-30bc-44c3-80bd-07ee6391e5cf] Successfully received 22 FlowFiles (455.78 KB) from Peer[url=nifi://212.76.88.137:25294] in 4740 milliseconds at a rate of 96.14 KB/sec
2023-04-27 15:03:22,838 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-1165] o.a.n.r.p.s.SocketFlowFileServerProtocol SocketFlowFileServerProtocol[CommsID=eac02335-3ac7-42bd-8779-4253e20fd36f] Successfully received 25 FlowFiles (168.09 KB) from Peer[url=nifi://212.76.88.137:9047] in 1217 milliseconds at a rate of 138.06 KB/sec
```

Comment: It's not clear what is the issue and why do you think you have one...